# Get all HTML visible inside of viewport after CSS was applied, before action returns

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

**Context** provided in case someone tells me that they have a much better approach.

I am trying to build a critical CSS path generator that would be easily integrated inside of a project's build process.

I wish to avoid using the few available javascript-based libraries because it would force me to install the whole npm/node/grunt & stuff stack in the project only for this task. These JS stacks really aren't part of the company's culture and it's best to avoid them on legacy projects such as this one.

The process I intend to use (simplified) for a given action/route is:

1. Checking for cached CSS. If found, skip to the step 7
2. Run the action normally
3. Render the razor view normally
4. Scan the styling resources used within the page and download them (the CSS bundles & stuff)
5. Run the "above fold HTML extractor" algorithm, which would return all the HTML that would be displayed within a viewport of arbitrary height (720p or something)
6. Determine what CSS would be applied to this HTML using the files downloaded in step 3 (I haven't determined how I'll do that yet)
7. Caching this CSS that was selected as "critical"
8. Injecting the CSS inline at the end of the `head` tag

The idea is that the pages on which this "critical" system is set up would be "pinged" right after the application was deployed, populating the critical CSS cache to avoid having the first organic human user have to wait for all this mess to happen.

**The problem** I'm currently trying to solve

In C#, how can I extract the HTML code that would be displayed within the viewport? I first thought about selenium WebDrive's C# API but I couldn't find any information on how to get the HTML shown within the viewport and I need no less than a fully-featured headless API HTML renderer to be able to determine what HTML is above the fold **after the CSS was applied**.

**The question**

How can I programmatically get, in C#, the HTML displayed in a viewport after the CSS was applied? If it is possible using Selenium WebDriver, how to achieve it. If not, are there any other options that I could use to achieve this result?

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) might help you figure out which elements are being displayed.

Comment: It is still en issue, but this project is "put on hold" so to speak. Thanks for the tip, I'll see to using it once I start working on this project again.