# Extrat or truncate DOM - Keep only what is within the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Context**

This question is a follow-up of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53556289/6838730). I've decided that executing a JS script through a selenium WebDriver was the best way to achieve my goal.

**I need**

to get all the HTML (ultimately as a C# string) visible to the user that is within the viewport

**I tried**

Selecting the whole dom and traversing it, checking for each element if it is visible AND within the viewport and keeping it only if both conditions are true. But this means that when it reads the `body` element, it see it is in fact within the viewport and it has the `:visible` state so I add the element to a `visible` list.

But it adds the element along with all of its children ... and so all the DOM that is a child of `body` is selected regardless of its visibility!

Below is the code I came up with after quite a bit of tinkering. It's partly built on top of SO answers

```
function isVisible(el)
{
    return $(el).is(':visible');
}

function isInViewport(el)
{
    var elementTop = $(el).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(el).outerHeight();
    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

var all = $('*');

var selected = [];

for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++)
{
    if (isInViewport(all[i]) && isVisible(all[i]))
    {
        // This adds the current element, but that means all its children are also implicitly added !
        selected.push(all[i]);
    }
}

// So when I convert the list to a string I end up with basicaly the whole dom except for the `head` tag and its content ...
return $(selected).filter(':not(html)').html();
```

Comment: The thing you need to change is the order in which you traverse the DOM. You need to go from deepest to shallowest, not the other way around, and exclude parents where not _all_ children are inside the viewport.

Comment: That seems so obvious now that you said it ... thanks I'll try that :-)